# Return the total number of poems, the average character count for poems that mention death and poems that mention love

Tags: postgresql

SELECT text
FROM poem
WHERE poem.text ILIKE '%love%'
OR poem.text ILIKE '%death%'

this is the code that I have. I need it to return the character count of the text column under poems. one for love and one for death and how many poems were written. I also need it to be one continual piece of code.

Comment: Where are you doing the average character count?

Comment: Do you want a single result (row), or two results (one for the poems with death and one for the poems with love)?

Comment: haven't gotten there yet

Comment: one for each please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want two [filtered aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) for this:

```
SELECT
  avg(char_length(text)) FILTER (WHERE poem.text ILIKE '%love%') AS average_of_love_poems,
  avg(char_length(text)) FILTER (WHERE poem.text ILIKE '%death%') AS average_of_death_poems
FROM poem
```